# How to create a 7zip archive of files from a directory, excluding existing archives?

Tags: bash, shell-script, terminal, file-types

Want to **7zip** all files in *root/current* folder *except* for all **zip-files AND all 7z/7zip files**. I can only get one of these to work at a time in one `if !` statement:

```
for file in ./test2/*
do

    if ! { `file $file  | grep -i zip > /dev/null 2>&1` && `file $file  | grep -i 7z > /dev/null 2>&1`; }; then 

    ## Most of the zip utilities contain "zip" when checked for file type. 
    ## grep for the expression that matches your case

      7z a -mx0 -mmt2 -tzip "${file%/}.cbz" "$file"
      rm -rf "$file"

    fi
done
```

I have followed the "list" `{list;};` standards from other posts, but no luck.

---

My current solution is to ***nest*** `if` statements, like so:

```
for file in ./test2/*
do
    if ! `file $file  | grep -i 7z > /dev/null 2>&1`; then 

        if ! `file $file  | grep -i zip > /dev/null 2>&1`; then 
        ## first if its not 7z, now also if not zip.

          7z a -mx0 -mmt2 -tzip "${file%/}.cbz" "$file"
          rm -rf "$file"

        fi

    fi

done
```

Only thing left is exclude directories. All files go. How to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the output of `file` separately and then use that in multiple tests, or in a `case` statement:

```
for file in ./test2/*; do
    filetype=$( file "$file" )

    if [[ $filetype == *7z*  ]] ||
       [[ $filetype == *zip* ]]
    then
        # skip these
        continue
    fi

    # rest of body of loop here
done
```

Or,

```
for file in ./test2/*; do
    filetype=$( file "$file" )

    case $filetype in
       *7z*)  continue ;;  # skip these
       *zip*) continue ;;  # and these
    esac

    # rest of body of loop here
done
```

You may also want to get `file` to output the MIME type instead of a free form text string.  That could be done with `file -i` and would make the script slightly more portable (if you care about that).  See the `file(1)` manual (`man 1 file`).

To exclude directories, just use

```
if [ -d "$file" ]; then
    continue
fi
```

before the call to `file`.

Alternatively, use short-circuit syntax:

```
[ -d "$file" ] && continue
```

The `continue` statement, in all instances where it's used above, will skip the remainder of the current iteration and continue with the next iteration of the loop.  I'm using when I have determined that the current value of `$file` is something that we *don't* want to process in this iteration.  This is the opposite of what you do, which is to try to craft a set of tests for when the operations *should* be performed.

A `/bin/sh`-compatible script would look like this in the end:

```
#!/bin/sh

for file in ./test2/*; do
    [ -d "$file" ] && continue

    filetype=$( file "$file" )

    case $filetype in
       *7z*)  continue ;;  # skip these
       *zip*) continue ;;  # and these
    esac

    # rest of body of loop here
done
```

Comment: Works perfectly. I put the: `if [ -d "$file" ]; then ... ` before the 7z line. Does just what I want.

Comment: @andyNilson No. As I mentioned, it should go before the call to `file`, i.e. before assigning anything to `filetype`. Doing it later means you're calling `file` unnecessary.

Comment: @ Kusalananda. Do i add it to `filetype`, to the `for` statement or in between?

Comment: @andyNilson Between. The test of whether `$file` is a directory should be the first thing that happens in the loop. If it is a directory, the rest of that iteration should be skipped with `continue`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. Added it before the `filetype`. Now working smoothly. Your last example for `bin/sh` works perfectly. My own `7z` though, had to be fitted with `-aou` to keep it from overwriting files. As some files created already had 7z versions. Posting it above as a final solution.

Comment: I missed the accepting the answer bit. And I guess to the next guy no, not without having the very precise issue. Hence the this specific forum. Removed the last bit again.